# How to get user input to search a file in Python?

Tags: python

I have this code that searches all the files from the given directory, but I want to change it so that it can search a file from the users input? and then ask again if the file is not found? The following code i have is:

```
import os
import sys
from stat import *


def depthsearch(directory):
    for files in os.listdir(directory):
        fileItem = os.path.join(directory, files)
        fileItemStatInfo = os.stat(fileItem)
        if S_ISDIR(fileItemStatInfo.st_mode):
            depthsearch(fileItem)
        elif S_ISREG(fileItemStatInfo.st_mode):
            print("Found File:", fileItem)

depthsearch("C:")
```

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
depthsearch(raw_input())  # or 'input()' for Python 3
```

To check if a given string represents a valid directory, you can use [`os.path.isdir()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.isdir). So you could wrap your call to `depthsearch()` in a while loop that keeps asking the user for input until they provide a valid directory.

Comment: Hi there, Im pretty new to python programming, could you show me an example of this please? thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can get input by using:

[Python 2.X's `raw_input` function:](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input)

```
s = raw_input()
```

[Python 3.X's `input` function:](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#input)

```
s = input()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def depthsearch(directory, fileName):
    for files in os.listdir(directory):
        fileItem = os.path.join(directory, files)
        fileItemStatInfo = os.stat(fileItem)
        if S_ISDIR(fileItemStatInfo.st_mode):
            depthsearch(fileItem,filename)
        elif S_ISREG(fileItemStatInfo.st_mode or (files==filename):
            print("Found File:", fileItem)

depthsearch("C:", "python.exe")
```

This allow you to search a file in a directory. It just test if the name are the same.